# Unable to build entity manager factory ( Hibernate JPA )

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

Estou tentado realizar uma conexão com o Hibernate e o JPA, porém ao tentar criar a conexão ou persistir algum dado ele executa o seguinte erro:

> dez 04, 2018 2:02:45 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
>   logDeprecation WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated
>   javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
>   [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use
>   [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead. dez 04, 2018
>   2:02:45 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation WARN:
>   HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated
>   javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
>   [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use
>   [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead. dez 04, 2018
>   2:02:45 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation WARN:
>   HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated
>   javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
>   [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use
>   [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead. dez 04, 2018
>   2:02:45 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper
>   logPersistenceUnitInformation INFO: HHH000204: Processing
>   PersistenceUnitInfo [     name: context   ...] dez 04, 2018 2:02:45 PM
>   org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core
>   {4.3.0.Final} dez 04, 2018 2:02:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment
>    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found dez 04, 2018
>   2:02:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider INFO:
>   HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist dez 04, 2018 2:02:45 PM
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {4.0.4.Final} dez 04, 2018 2:02:45 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool
>   (not for production use!) **Unable to build entity manager factory**

***Meu pom.xml***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>gpnet.com.br.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>Api</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <spring-version>5.0.4.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <jpa-version>2.0.4.RELEASE</jpa-version>
        <hibernate-version>4.3.0.Final</hibernate-version>
        <mysql-version>6.0.4</mysql-version>
        <hibernate-jpa-version>1.0.0.Final</hibernate-jpa-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${jpa-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-jpa-version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

***Meu persistence.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="context" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <!-- Configurações da string de conexão -->
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
            <!-- Linguagem que o Hibernate irá usar para se comunicar com o banco -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5Dialect"/>
            <!-- Mostrar as queries no console -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <!-- Atualizar o banco de acordo com alguma alteração -->

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

***Minha classe Main***

```
package gpnet.com.br.main;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;

import gpnet.com.br.models.Usuario;
import gpnet.com.br.util.JPAUtil;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Usuario user = new Usuario();
        user.setNome("jose");
        user.setEmail("jose.silva");
        user.setSenha("123456");

        try {
            EntityManager em;
            EntityManagerFactory fact = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("context"); // Here it crashes
            em = fact.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(user);
            em.getTransaction().commit();

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao analisar melhor faltaram algumas dependencias no ***pom.xml***:

```
 <!-- API JPA -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- JXB -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Como também no ***persistence.xml*** o `hibernate.dialect` tem que estar de acordo com a versão do banco que você estiver usando.

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect"/>
```

No meu caso a versão *5.7 do MYSQL*

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente, a implementação do JPA que você está usando esta depreciada.

No seu persistence.xml troque a  tag provider por isso: `<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>`

Note também que você precisa indicar ao JPA quais classes são entidades a serem persistidas, adicionando essa tag após declarar o provider:

```
<class>gpnet.com.br.models.Usuario</class>
```

Comment: Efetuei as mudanças mas o erro continua o mesmo `Unable to build entity manager factory`

Comment: Acho que pode ter outro erro no persistence.xml. Você colocou o nome do `<persistence unit/>` como "context", mas na sua url do banco, o nome está como "jpa". Tenta trocar essa url pra: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/context

Comment: Troquei, criei o banco como context, porém nada.Continua dando esse erro `Unable to build entity manager factory` .

Comment: Talvez alguma dependência do maven esteja desatualizada, pelo o que eu sei o hibernate-core é a nova distribuição e tem todos os componentes que o hibernate precisa. Tenta tirar essa dependência: `hibernate-entitymanager` do maven e colocar o hibernate-core mais atualizado, desse link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.3.7.Final

Comment: retirei todas as dependências e deixei somente o `hibernate` e o conector `mysql` todas com a ultima versão. O erro agora mudou: `Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]`

Comment: Está difícil de dizer ao certo qual o problema. Eu tenho uma aplicação com hibernate e está rodando de boa com apenas essas duas dependências: `mysql-connector` nesse link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.13; e `hibernate-core` nesse link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.3.7.Final. Posso te passar a base do meu código pra você tentar corrigir o seu

Comment: agradeceria pois já atualizei todas as dependências e o erro persiste.

Comment: https://github.com/andre237/Hibernate-e-JPA-Test. Eu uso Intellij mas dá uma olhada no `src` que tem tudo que precisa.

Comment: vlw cara ajudou muito, porém acabei descobrindo que faltava algumas dependências e o `hibernate.dialect` não estava de acordo com o banco selecionado.